# Apache rewrite для Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Помогите переписать rewrite для nginx

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /loader.php;
}
```